# Sabre cancel itinerary segments error (OTA_CancelRQ)

Tags: xml, api, soap, sabre

I am trying to cancel itinerary segment through [Sabre API (OTA_CancelRQ)](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/air/book/Cancel_Itinerary_Segments).

I followed [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35408584/cancel-a-complete-pnr#answer-35425073) and I could reach step number 3 ( OTA_CancelRQ ).

- STEP1: SessionCreateRQ
- STEP2: GetReservationRQ
- STEP3: OTA_CancelRQ
- STEP4: EndTransactionRQ
- STEP5: SessionCloseRQ

Currently I am stuck at step number 3, it always fail with this below error message

> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'OTA_CancelRQ'.

### Request Data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId>sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId>webservices.sabre.com</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId>****</CPAId>
         <ConversationId>convid</ConversationId>
         <Service>OTA_CancelLLSRQ</Service>
         <Action>OTA_CancelLLSRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>msgid112</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2020-04-20T09:25:27Z</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2020-04-20T09:25:27Z</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="Base64Binary" valueType="String">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1587378430974!2968!17</BinarySecurityToken>
      </Security>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <OTA_CancelRQ Version="2.0.2">
         <Segment Type="entire" />
      </OTA_CancelRQ>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

---

### Response Data

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" soap-env:mustUnderstand="1">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">webservices.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">sample.url.of.sabre.client.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>****</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>convid</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service>OTA_CancelLLSRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>OTA_CancelLLSRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1447971375167810151</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2020-04-20T10:25:17</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>msgid112</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/ACPCRTC!ICESMSLB\/CRT.LB!1587378313106!6744!9</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap-env:Header>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <soap-env:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap-env:Client.Validation</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <stl:ApplicationResults xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="NotProcessed">
               <stl:Error timeStamp="2020-04-20T05:25:17-05:00" type="Validation">
                  <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                     <stl:Message>cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'OTA_CancelRQ'.</stl:Message>
                     <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.CLIENT.VALIDATION_FAILED</stl:ShortText>
                  </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
               </stl:Error>
            </stl:ApplicationResults>
         </detail>
      </soap-env:Fault>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you miss namespaces

For example

```
<OTA_CancelRQ Version="2.0.2" xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Segment Type="entire"/>
</OTA_CancelRQ>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the soap request body as following:

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<OTA_CancelRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.0.2">
<Segment Type="entire"/>
```

This should resolve the issue being faced.

Hope it helps!

Thank You!